# Limits as x approaches 0

Tags: education

[image]

I was wondering how this worked when submitted, anything over 0 was infinite.

Comment: Have you tried l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Are you familiar with [indeterminate forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)? Sure, if your limit looks like $\frac{k}{0}$ and $k \ne 0$ then you're going to have an infinite limit, but if the functions on the top and bottom both tend to zero then you need to do more work (e.g. applying [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) before you can determine the limit. And sure enough, $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = 0$.

Comment: $$\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}=\sin x$$ and see 
[this][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/75151#75151

Comment: Why was this answer converted to comment?

Comment: the answer is 1 though!

Comment: I'm not sure because the name of the worksheet I was doing was Limits at Removable Discontinuities using trig, from AB calc

Answer (score 1):

well, $$ \cos( \frac{\pi}{2} - x ) = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} + x ) = \sin x  $$.

Hence,

$$ \frac{ \sin x}{x} \to_{x \to 0 } 1 $$

Comment: this should be accepted as an answer